# How to split HTML DIV TABLE into 2 sections?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a div pricing table with 10 columns. Please see below for the example table snippet.

The issue I'm having now it that the table is too wide on the screen. I would like to make first 5 items on the top and remaining 5 items underneath it.

Can it be done by using css to split the table into two sections?

Thanks!

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">Item 1</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 2</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 3</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 4</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 5</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 6</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 7</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 8</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 9</div>
<div class="divTableCell">Item 10</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">aaa</div>
<div class="divTableCell">bbb</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ccc</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ddd</div>
<div class="divTableCell">eee</div>
<div class="divTableCell">fff</div>
<div class="divTableCell">ggg</div>
<div class="divTableCell">hhh</div>
<div class="divTableCell">iii</div>
<div class="divTableCell">jjj</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: try:   .divTableRow { display: inline-block; }

Comment: I would honestly ditch the idea of displaying a table, and use flex layout instead, because it's intended for this kind of behavior.

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster Thanks but it is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/b7ehnuk2/

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with CSS only using that DOM structure. You need to change your structure, maybe two tables one after the other.

Side note: you should use `table` elements instead of `div`s for tables. Also look into flexbox.

Here's an example with minimal changes:

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 1</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 2</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 3</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 4</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">aaa</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">bbb</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ccc</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ddd</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">eee</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 6</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 7</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 8</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 9</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">Item 10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">fff</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">ggg</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">hhh</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">iii</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">jjj</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```